# window.history.pushstate with non latin characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm debugging a javascript app (using Chrome dev tools) and I have problems with calling window.history.pushstate.

After the following call Chrome crashes/freezes:

```
window.history.pushstate( {}, “Espa%C3%B1a”, “Espa%C3%B1a” );
```

Looks like only the third parameter is the bad one, because making it “” works.

I have tested it with Maxthon too, it adds strange characters to the address bar in an endless loop

Any ideas on this?

Is there may be a way to easy convert it to “Espana” with only Latin characters?

Comment: `pushState` should be `pushState` and `“”` should be `""`. Are you using them correctly in your code ? (*it works fine in windows Firefox 36.0, Chrome 40, IE 11*)

Comment: for removing diacritics (convert to ascii) see https://github.com/mplatt/fold-to-ascii-js

Comment: Sorry for the formating issues, they are related to writing the text originaly in Word and copy it. ;-)

I use `window.History.pushState( {}, "Espa%C3%B1a", "Espa%C3%B1a" );` in code running on Chrome 40.